# Qual a diferença entre usar o appendChild e o insertAdjacentHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Em um código do qual vou ter que adicionar um elemento dentro de uma DIV. Qual a diferença entre criar primeiro o elemento e adiciona-lo a div através do appendChild e fazer `DIV.insertAdjacentHTML('html correspondente ao elemento')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`appendChild` insere um **elemento html** ao DOM, **no final da lista de filhos**, por isso precisa criar um elemento:

```
let aBlock = document.createElement('block').appendChild( document.createElement('b') );
```

`insertAdjacentHTML` **recebe uma string html ou xml**, ou seja, faz um parse para um objeto, e **insere numa posição específica**, que pode ser `beforebegin`, `afterbegin`, `beforeend` ou `afterend`:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');
```

Ambos exemplos tirados da documentação do mozilla:

[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Em resumo, `appendChild` adiciona um elemento ao final da lista de filhos, `insertAdjacentHTML` converte uma string e insere numa posição específica.

Aqui um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("bt").addEventListener('click', function() { 
   // appendChild
   let l1 = document.createElement('li');
   l1.innerHTML = "appendChild";
   document.getElementById("ul1").appendChild(l1);

   // insertAdjacentHTML
   document.getElementById('ul2').insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<li>insertAdjacentHTML</li>");
});
```

```html
<span>Lista 1:</span>
<ul id="ul1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<span>Lista 2:</span>
<ul id="ul2">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<button id="bt">Testar</button>
```